# Someone she fears come or comes?

Tags: grammar

I do not know if this is true or not. Please, help me

“Someone she fears come.” or “someone she fears comes.”

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence, the subject of `come` is `someone`, which is a third person singular noun, so `come` should be inflected as `comes`.